# mediaquerys and the place of including

Tags: sass

Developed with ADOBE Bracket and Koala as IDE for Sass / SCSS.

I have defined mediaqueries in an external stylesheet and included with *@import "query.scss";* in the head of *basic.scss*. The queries are completely ignored. Only when I enter them at the end (!) Of the *basic.scss* directly, they have an effect after the compilation to *basic.css*. Why?

I was of the opinion that the location of the query definition is irrelevant and the action is always read and applied at the occurrence of the event, regardless of the location of the definition. At least I have developed this experience without Sass / SCSS.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a difference between the two generated basic.css? Check if the query.scss file is referenced correctly with e.g. adding a background color to the body in query.scss and see if it's applied.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your imported style sheet contains rules surrounded by a media query that are supposed to override the default styles? Media queries do not increase CSS specificity at all, therefore order still matters. With CSS and SASS/SCSS for rules with the same specificity, the last rules is the one that applies. In this example, the class original has a font size of 20 and the class new will show a font size of 42px;

SCSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px)  {
  .original {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}

.original {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.new {
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
  .new {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="original">Original Styles</div>
<div class="new">New Styles</div>
```

You can see it in action here:
https://jsfiddle.net/2y7Lramt/